# How can i summon a villager with a trade that i can only place down on certain blocks and break certain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have seen maps with villagers with custom trades. The item that can be traded have qualities that make it so that it can only be placed down on certain blocks or break certain blocks and I want to know how to do this.

Comment: Which edition are you using?

Comment: 1.16rc version.

Comment: Remember you can always upvote and accept my answer if you think it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command, assuming you are using Java Edition. You must use a command block to execute this command.

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{type:plains,profession:farmer,level:99},Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:999999,priceMultiplier:0,demand:1,specialPrice:0,buy:{id:dirt},sell:(What you want)}}]}}
```

Replace the `(What you want)` with the item and its NBT that you want. Here are some examples:

```
minecraft:stone{HideFlags:16,CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass_block"]} 1
```

```
minecraft:wooden_pickaxe{HideFlags:8,CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone"]} 1
```

[This website](https://www.gamergeeks.nz/apps/minecraft/mob-generator/summon-villager) may also help with your efforts.

For the full command, here it is:

```
/summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{type:plains,profession:farmer,level:99},Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:999999,priceMultiplier:0,demand:1,buy:{id:dirt,Count:1},sell:{id:stone_button,Count:1,tag:{HideFlags:16,CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:grass_block"]}}}]}}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: @S.Moffat This is for minecraft java 1.14+

Comment: Can you tell me the hole command like just say the command that makes the villager trades 1 stone button for stone that can be placed on grass tell me that command.

Comment: Just say that's what I wan't

Comment: @S.Moffat I have updated my post to include the whole command.

Comment: With NoAI and persestant and Invulnerable

Comment: Not working. :(

Comment: It's just dirt for stone button it cant be placed on anything

Comment: @S.Moffat Try and go to this website and see if it helps. If so, you can upvote and accept my answer if it helps. https://www.gamergeeks.nz/apps/minecraft/mob-generator/summon-villager

Comment: But is there a way to get the sell to be placed on certain blocks on the website?

Comment: I tried its air for air

Comment: WAIT YOUR COMMAND WORKED THANK YOU SO MUCH  the full one.

Comment: it just doesnt say

Comment: what to place it on

Comment: Oh nvm i got it

Comment: @S.Moffat You can upvote and accept my answer if you think it helps.

Comment: But just how do i do that?

Comment: @S.Moffat There is a check mark button below the "vote" up/down area. Click on that to accept.